# A plea against regex dogmatism

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting-fraud, regex

Note:

- This is about a *perceived* pattern of down-votes.
- *If no such pattern actually exists, this post is moot*; if there is such a pattern, I hope the users who contribute to it either reconsider their behavior or engage in a discussion. I'm deliberately not linking to specific posts so as to avoid a distraction. If no one else has noticed such a pattern, so be it - but I wonder if my perception is indicative of an actual problem in the community.

Regexes (regular expressions) - love them or hate them - can offer *powerfully concise*, if *potentially obscure* solutions, *where appropriate*.

However, not every *question* tagged with [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) calls for an actual regex *answer* - I'm sure we're all familiar with the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/248777).

*Anecdotally, in my personal experience*, I perceive the following pattern:

- Answers to questions tagged [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) that *aren't regex-based* - whether helpful or not, whether *more appropriate* than a regex solution or not - are *methodically down-voted*, *without explanation*.
- Note that I am talking about helpful / more appropriate solutions *in the primary language context of a given question*, not off-topic answers along the lines of "Why don't you do this in language X instead"?

Needless to say, if such a pattern indeed exists, it is counterproductive and should stop.

---

*Update* (14 Jan 2023):

The problem affects [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) posts more generally, *suggesting* a pattern of both aggressively down-voting / closing as a duplicate / deleting *questions*, as well as *seemingly* methodically down-voting even answers that *do* provide regex solutions, on the *suspected* grounds of the question being subpar / a duplicate / too trivial a variation, as the following posts attest:

- [Please stop deleting our content without coherent reasons (regex tag)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421392/45375)
- [What should we do when one person tries to delete every duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405460/45375)
- [What's wrong with my answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419923/45375)
- [What to do when a community is openly hostile?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421370/45375)

  - On meta meta note: It is illuminating to see the net tally of votes on that post (+10/-28 as of this writing), and the fact that the OP has (regrettably) since deleted their account - *presumably* (also) as a result of how their post was received.
- The posts above link to many others expressing similar sentiments with respect to [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) SO posts, though they may not all be tagged as such *here*.

  - Here's a [dynamic query showing all currently `regex`-tagged Meta SO posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex).

Comment: I've noticed users posting regex solutions to Questions and *then* added the regex tag themselves :O

Comment: Ehh, I have mixed feelings. Why not remove the regex tag if you think the question should not be answered with a RegEx solution?

Comment: This is overall a problem with SO. Good engineering demands that we propose the most suitable solution, "staying on-topic" demands that we sometimes hand out sub-optimal solutions. But I don't think there's a way around it, or people would be tempted to post blatantly off-topic solutions. It may be that the OP should actually have asked a more open-ended design question, but then SO isn't a good place either and "software engineering" is a lost cause, so you'd have to take the question outside the SE network.

Comment: Yep indeed, I 100% recognize the Behaviour/Workflow described by @OP, it also takes place regularly in the "small" Tag ([tag:imacros]) I answer..., ... where (for 90% 1-Rep) Users ask a (usually Low Qlt) Qt they think can only be solved with `REGEX`, tag it with [tag:regex], => "annoy" the `REGEX` Gurus watching that Tag, => get a few Downvotes, I post a simpler Solution that doesn't even use any `REGEX`. + Those 1-Rep Users usually never follow up (and even less accept Answers, ah-ah...!), and those Qt's then get deleted 30 days later by 'Roomba'...

Comment: I don't think I follow your meaning. @Ora  Who is talking about 5 identical comments? Do you mean if there where "pile-on downvotes" -- that is not constructive, I agree.

Comment: @mickmackusa yes, if you wanted to downvote for the same reason someone else did

Comment: @OrangeDog Why would you want to do that? If the post is already going to Roomba? Is it to make sure that the poster never gets back up?

Comment: Could you construct a SEDE query or a sufficiently large set of samples evidencing these claims? Preferably in the question itself for future reference.

Comment: @mickmackusa, I think your idea re making it more expensive to down-vote without comment is an interesting one, but, as the exchange here shows, there are challenges around it. Either way, it deservers to be its own post, which I encourage you to create.

Comment: @E_net4thecurator, I stressed the personal angle for a reason: I don't have evidence, and I wouldn't know how to construct such a query, not least because it would require scanning the _content_ of answers for the presence of actual regexes. My motivation was twofold: to ascertain whether I am alone in my perception, and to - hopefully - get the - presumptive - users who engage in the behavior described to reconsider or at least engage in a discussion about it.

Comment: For one, mere perceptions and gut feelings can be deceiving, whereas concrete data would be factual. Yes, engaging in that research to identify key samples, even if manually, would not only help present the pattern in a non-ambiguous, but also make a stronger claim about its pertinence in the platform.

Comment: [This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411113) I asked not long ago is relevant to what's being asked here. If you feel that some people are voting in a way which significantly harms the contributions around that tag, you have to build a convincing case.

Comment: @E_net4thecurator Hard data is undoubtedly preferable, and I understand that the subjectivity and vagueness of my plea / invitation to a discussion is unsatisfying.
But even manual research would ultimately be subjective: how do you prove that a given, comment-less down-vote happened for the reason put forth in this question? So, no, I don't think a convincing case can be built here, only a _plea_ not to engage in a _suspected_ pattern - even though the hypothetical target  audience may never see or heed it. nvoigt's answer provides good insights into the potential psychology.

Comment: I notice another pattern : There are quite a few complaints for the `regex` tag, and even though they don't include any "link to specific posts so as to avoid a distraction", they seem to often be linked to a specific user which isn't too hard to find on https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/topusers.

Comment: @EricDuminil Does that pattern concern the actions of said user, or does it concern claims to protect anonymity when that's apparently not actually the case?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: It wasn't clear indeed. The pattern concerns the actions of said user.

Comment: Related: [How to answer a question when the right answer may not be a good idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372402), [Answering a Question Vs. Solving a Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17627), [Is "Don't do it" a valid answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891), [Does Stack Exchange allow for answers which question the validity or stance of the original question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263661)

Comment: Another perfect example of this popped up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69769839/how-to-implement-do-while-loop-only-using-goto-in-c-language) even as I was reading this. Normally I'd just leave a comment, but to experiment I posted the correct answer instead of answering what the OP asked for. Social experiment, watch me get down voted to oblivion :)

Comment: It's really rather difficult to address this without actual examples, or even a specific *theoretical* example. I also don't see a convincing argument here that the downvotes you perceive are occurring exclusively because of the [tag:regex] tag being included on the question, and it's impossible for us to determine that for ourselves without, well, examples. To whit, this question ultimately is just asking users to contour their voting habits to your personal preferences, which I don't think is particularly productive or realistic.

Comment: @TylerH, there's nothing to address here. The best this post can hope for is to a describe a _perceived_ pattern of down-voting that is based on _formal_ criteria rather than the merits of answers and plead for it to stop / ask those who do it - if they exist - to discuss. Criticism of this pattern is not a personal preference. As I said: My plea is moot if no such pattern exists; it cannot be proven, but at least _anecdotally_ others have seen it too, as the responses here attest;  nvoigt's answer paints a compelling portrait as to what the underlying motivation may be.

Comment: i downvote most questions that contains regex related things on the tag i watch becasue most of the time it is uselessly complex and slow.

Comment: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think
'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems." http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247

Comment: @mh-cbon - why should a question be downvoted for it?  I think you might want to downvote an _answer_ suggesting it, yes, if you feel that way, but someone asking for help?

Comment: I can certainly legitimately imagine scenarios where a question is tagged with a language (because a particular regex syntax is needed) but at the same time should be answered with only a regex because the solution constraints require it. That is, we may be dealing with an engine or application that is specifically processing regexes only, and we can't just slap our own custom code on the problem even if it's simpler. I do image such questions to be uncommon, and they should, ideally, clearly state their constraints. At the same time, I don't imagine anyone would then answer differently.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Yes, I'm sure there are _specific cases_ where a regex answer is not only appropriate, but also _required_.
However, this post is about something different: Objecting to the - perceived - _methodical_ down-voting based on the purely _formal_
criterion of answering a regex-tagged question with a non-regex solution - irrespective of the specifics of the question and the answer.

Comment: I thought I was the only one seeing this, perfectly explained. Thanks for taking the time to post this!

Comment: @EricDuminil I have seen the same thing repeatedly.

Comment: As it happens, I've recently been thinking about why the regex tag seems to cause even more friction between curators, askers and answerers than usual for Stack Overflow. I'm definitely going to have to take this discussion into account to come up with a proper explanation.

Comment: Quality is in the eye of the beholder. I mean, to some, questions asked on SO seem trivial and are downvoted right away (or closed as a duplicate). Sometimes for good reason, sometimes simply because they themselves follow a different standard. This became so obvious to me that I went from liking to answer/help people on this tag, to staying away in most cases. Frankly put; what fun is it to have your answer downvoted without any apparent reason. I wonder if people downvote answers just because they didn't like the question to begin with. IMHO That's just toxic.

Comment: I hear you, @JvdV. Anecdotally, I've seen the additional pattern you describe too, especially after duplicate disputes (which too seem to be especially common in the regex tag), and I agree that it is toxic.

Comment: You see this issue everywhere that votes exist. Some of the world feels that they have no need or reason to seek out information and want to copy / paste their way through life. Some feel the best answer is more important than anything else, even at the cost of writing an essay answer to a multiple choice question. Neither wants to hear from the other side because one is lazy and the other is pedantic. Voting typically becomes a means for vengeance, not an evaluation.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes, indeed. That kind of answer is called a [frame challenge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263661/does-stack-exchange-allow-for-answers-which-question-the-validity-or-stance-of-t).

For example someone asks how to parse an HTML document using a REGEX and you answer that doing that is a fool's errand and they should use an HTML parser package/dependency of their choice.

Technically, you have not answered their REGEX question. Practically, they got the advice they needed to get, whether they realize it or not.

The problem is, that for every tag (whether it's regex or dungeons and dragons or your favorite pet, it really doesn't matter) there are fanbois. People so obsessed with their favorite solution, that it has become their *only* solution, to every question. The fact that alternatives exist does not fit into their world view. And they will downvote you, for the perceived heresy of using a different solution to the problem.

It becomes very apparent, when you visit for example the workplace SE. You can post frame challenges. Many answers are. Sure, sometimes people think it's not useful, but you don't have fanbois that downvote you because you did not provide a solution for their favorite tag. I mean I get that. There are no fanbois of German labor law. That stuff is so boring, if you provide an alternative, even people knowledgable in labor law are like "oh, yes, *please*".

That is the way it *should* be. Tags are information. This site is about the best solution to a problem.

But you will not get that anytime soon. People are just too attached to things they like. They become irrational. Human even :)

Comment: Are you suggesting that some of the accounts on this site are operated by *humans*? That's totally unacceptable, please flag all such accounts as soon as you see them.

Comment: Ah, yes, I have heard of a government conspiracy to that end. Big corporations are in on it, but I found evidence in some documentaries on those little indy platforms of truth, like Facebook and Youtube. It seems that the have indeed found a way to infiltrate us with a network of humans. It's frightening.

Comment: "I hope the roleplaying.se isn't still using `rand()` for their dice generation," said the `<random>` fanboi.

Comment: `Practically, they got the advice they needed to get, whether they realize it or not` except for all the cases where using a regexp is just fine. This is the issue I have with these kind of answers: they just *assume* that it's not a good solution because it doesn't cover all use cases, but a lot times you don't need to. I've parsed HTML with regexp and with real parsers. For a one-off, a regexp is just fine, and often easier and faster. If your HTML is predictable it can also be fine for some longer-term solutions (and may avoid a large dependency, which can come with their own problems).

Comment: @MartinTournoij How many questions do you see, that go into that much detail that you can *know for sure* that your solution with REGEX will be *just good enough* for their scenario? I have never seen such a question. And I would never assume that the tiny glimpse of their program they show in their question or their single data point they post as an example is really all they ever want.

Comment: I just don't assume anything one way or the other, especially since I like questions and answers to be useful in the long term. So I'd answer "here's how to fix your regexp" and then continue with "but there's some downsides with this, and have you also thought about this other solution?" That certainly seems better than going on off on a rant about how it's all "cancer" like that Zalgo regexp answer.

Comment: @nvoigt: And I'm tired of seeing this "they should use an HTML parser package/dependency of their choice" argument, linked to the obligatory https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/6419007. The only correct answer is "it depends". If you're sure that the desired info is written with the `/\bBlaBla_[A-Z]{3}_\d{5}\b/` pattern, somewhere in the HTML tree, then it's perfectly fine to search the corresponding regex, and make sure that there's exactly one match. Or you could use a huge XML parser library, with a brittle and unreadable XPATH, which will break next time the page design is updated.

Comment: Just one example of an answer which proudly claims to be robust because it uses an official HTML parsing library : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38081155/6419007
Too bad the `//a[contains(@href, "twitter.com")]` patterns also matches "http://www.malicioustwitter.com" or "http://maliciouswebsite.com/twitter.com". It's possible to write dangerous and brittle code with both regex or HTML parsers.

Comment: You can write bad code in any language and with any framework, just as one can crash and burn in any car. It's just a little more likely when speeding on a mountain road compared to driving slowly in the city. Parsing HTML with RegEx is speeding on a mountain road. Certainly the best option under certain circumstances, but not something I would advise people to do when they ask how to get from A to B.

Comment: @EricDuminil There's always nuance, and the merits of a given answer - whether it is regex-based or not - can only be judged individually.
I deliberately didn't link to specific answers, as I feared we would get lost in the specifics of discussing their particular merits.
My concern is about down-voting based purely on the _formal_ criterion that an answer to a regex-tagged question isn't
regex-based. Again, I only _suspect_ that people engage in such behavior, and
my post was about describing it as unproductive, to raise awareness and, if someone wants to defend it, to discuss it.

Comment: "If the only tool you have is a hammer, every problem looks like a nail" --Some Wise Person

Comment: @Conrado I think that was Stanley Burrell.

Comment: @Conrado: That's true. And it also applies to people who always want to use an HTML parser.