# What's wrong with my answer?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, specific-answer, voting-fraud, regex

I recently answered [an interesting question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73410584/5527985) and thought it was a good answer. Everybody was happy (the question was upvoted two times). Almost a day later I got three downvotes without any comments left. Even the question was downvoted and closed (besides I also can't see where the question would need "more focus").

There are tons of answers in the regex tag that have less explanation, so I don't think this can be the reason. Maybe I should have explained how *lookarounds* work, but my idea is to point to the right tool. It's not my task to explain basic mechanisms which can be read about in many sources. I usually link to an appropriate source for learning about such mechanism.

My understanding of votes was always to reward good ideas or criticize bad ones.

The regex tag has become more and more a somehow sad place during the last years. It's not so much fun anymore. Picking on others might be an explanation for the downvotes. Myself I have never "played" unfair here and indeed I'm a bit older guy who is not anyhow into doing such. I used my votes yet exclusively for technical evaluating and never for any emotional reasons.

Maybe it's just time to take a break (again). I don't write here for getting disturbed, but for having fun. The problem is, that I really like fiddling around with those questions on Stack Overflow and doing a bit hard with taking distance to it :)

Comment: *"My understanding of votes was always to reward good ideas or crictisize bad ones."* -- no one can explain why someone else votes the way that they do. If you feel your answer was good and helpful to future visitors, then that is rewarding in itself, no?

Comment: Don't see how the question lacks focus, maybe because it asks for regex solutions for either Notepad++ or Geany? Although I would have closed it as a duplicate of [Regex: match everything but a specific pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687620/regex-match-everything-but-a-specific-pattern)

Comment: Related: [Is there a better course of action for when detecting an unusual surge of complaints about downvotes around a specific tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411113/is-there-a-better-course-of-action-for-when-detecting-an-unusual-surge-of-compla) This seems a lot like a rant in disguise. Since one's votes are their own, there isn't that much that can be done about the allegedly excessive downvoting. One other thing to keep in mind is that downvotes on answers do not necessarily mean that the answer has something wrong.

Comment: Presuming the time with any significant attention is one page length in the default view (15 per page?) for [the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex?tab=newest&pagesize=15), you could wait that time (approx. 12 hours) + plus a margin of, say, 50%, 18 hours, before answering to avoid votes (in either direction). Or would it have been [FGITWed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19533#19533) by then? The more difficult and challenging question shouldn't be FGITWed. (If it is assumed patrollers use 50 per page, it would be about 30 hours + 50%)

Comment: I saw that question yesterday when it was posted, saw your answer & upvoted it, and... was waiting for this to happen. Why? Because that question "fits the pattern" of questions that would get (wrongfully) closed and deleted. See Broccoli's answer below to get an idea of what that pattern is. If you hang out in the regex tag a lot, you start to recognize this and predict which questions will be next. It's quite unfortunate and frustrating.

Comment: @PeterMortensen That wouldn't generally work in the [regex] tag. Some of the users who are doing this (deleting duplicates very frequently, wrongfully closing _sometimes_,etc.) are, no doubt, experts. And they would usually answer those kinds of questions within hours. Plus the 18h margin is also pretty small in this tag because they regularly check posts created in the last few days + posts that get bumped by answers. P.S. I said "some" because I don't want to name names.

Comment: And today that answer has a net-positive score. That's the game. If you suspect voting fraud then I would think a mod flag with relevant details/explanation would be more appropriate than a meta post asking effectively why people vote the way they do.

Comment: Allow me to just leave [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411129) here.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine wrongfully? I don't agree. If your focus is to maintain a library of canonical question answers then closing the question was the right approach (it should have been flagged as a duplicate but no one is perfect), if your focus is earning imaginary internet points instead of helping the community maintain the site, then all your points are valid.

Comment: @user692942 I frequent the [regex] tag and I VTC many regex questions myself. I can tell you that the [regex] tag has two problems (outlined in the post linked in Broccoli's answer below): 1) deleting (almost) every duplicate. 2) _sometimes_ closing wrongfully closing questions and insisting that should remain closed. If you don't believe the second problem exists, here are a couple of questions that I've answered [1](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71822237/revisions), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73031006). [1/2]

Comment: The first one was dup-hammered and accumulated two delete votes even though it clearly has absolutely nothing to do with the dup-target, until other users agreed with me and reopened the question. The second one was also dup-hammered and deleted despite the fact that it's clearly different from the dup-target. Those are just two of many other examples, and that's not even the bigger problem. Problem #1 is the most important one. [2/2]

Comment: Thank you for all the comments and answers. I learnt that Stack Overflow is much more than what can be perceived from being kind of trapped inside some specific tag like regex :) I appreciate the fair and friendly community and have a better feeling now.

Comment: For those that downvote or close an answer as described here, the definition of an [**XY problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) has no meaning (apparently, there only exists a **X-Problem** that should be answered). I am so happy with the persons that think outside the box and with that [actually **resolve** *my* (XY-)Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78032619/get-class-source/78033728#78033728).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is an issue [those in the regex tag are very familiar with.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405460/what-should-we-do-when-one-person-tries-to-delete-every-duplicate#comment827146_405495). It's not just you, it's most regulars.

> I would like to add to that I see (and have experienced personally) answers to such questions being downvoted without fail. Almost every answer to these questions is given a downvote before the question is deleted. Regardless of whether the answer is right or wrong. This indicates the user is in the habit of "punishing" users for answering questions they deem to be duplicates and not necessary for the site. Obviously we cannot tell people how to vote, but do you think voting on answers based on the merits of the question makes sense to you?

Nothing was wrong with your answer. It's just that a few [(or not?)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/405468) users appear to downvote answers to questions they close - which has the chilling effect of putting off other good-faith participants like yourself.

([Or perhaps the downvoters aren't the close voters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388686/), and the very high correlation of downvotes on such questions is just a coincidence.)

> [Is it okay to answer in regex tag without their approval?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/405481)
>
> No. Because I find in many occasions even in the last couple of days, the same guys closing questions that are not remotely dupes as dupes while gleefully answering dupe questions.

I apologize if this seems like an accusation against individuals, but I don't see how to address OP's question without pointing it out.

Comment: Since a comment from another question was quoted, I think it's worth quoting a few more replying to that one: _"if you consider the question not having value I can imagine that the answers have no value and as such warrant a down vote."_ [ref](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405460/#comment827193_405495) _"Voting is anonymous and you're not a moderator, hence you have no idea who is downvoting those answers, so your accusation is based on an assumption that you cannot prove. Be very careful."_ [ref](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405460/#comment827227_405495)

Comment: Great. If there aren't already enough problems that the site has, apparently there are also powermongers.

Comment: With a subject like Regex, you'll be hard pressed to find a "unique" question that doesn't fit an already highly upvoted canonical target. Unfortunately, the question showed no attempt the "Needs more focus" was probably justified but the duplicate even more so.

Comment: I don't think you can assume that the question closers also downvoted the answer. I had a look at the aggregated voting stats for one of the closers and there was a fairly eye watering ratio of 242 upvotes vs 44,506 downvotes. But also they had voted on 43,789 questions and only 959 answers so don't appear to be habitually "punishing" answerers to bad questions.  

Comment: @MartinSmith I know it’s totally anecdotal and usually I’d agree  but anyone who has posted on the regex tag knows exactly what happens. There’s only so many times a close vote from a certain user -> downvote perfectly good answers pairing happens before it stops being coincidental.

Comment: @user438383 and yet evidence suggest the contrary. So, maybe bring other evidence outside of casual observations.

Comment: "Nothing was wrong with your answer. It's just that a few (or not?) users appear to downvote answers to questions they close" I don't understand what the link has to do with this. The link is about a suspicion of coordination in delete votes on questions; what does that have to do with question-close-voters downvoting answers?

Comment: @user692942 I feel like a big part of the problem is that almost every question in the tag is bad, but it's *harder than usual to explain why* they're bad, because of the nature of regex. I might try to write a blog article about it at some point.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is simple.

The OP didn't check to see if there was an existing canonical answer. If they had they would see there are already highly upvoted answers that cover the problem which we should be pointing people to via the flagging/close voting system.

It's not their fault though, the site incentivises answering over content moderation so there is always going to be a conflict.

Answer (score 3):

> Maybe I should have explained how lookarounds work, but my idea is to point to the right tool. It's not my task to explain basic mechanisms which can be read about in many sources.

I disagree with this sentiment, strongly.

The lookaheads are the key part of the answer. They are a tricky tool that behave unlike normal expressions. Using two kinds of the tool is extra tricky in how they work together.

Yet the answer does not explain their use. It does not identify their patterns. Heck, it does not even *name* them other than with a much broader category.

All the relevant information to make the approach *generally useful* [is not in the answer itself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).<sup>1</sup> This is doubly striking since the answer *does explain basic mechanisms* that are relevant for just the specific task.

---

<sup>1</sup>

> #### How do I write a good answer?
>
> ##### Provide context for links
>
> [...] Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Links to other websites should always be helpful, but avoid making it necessary to click on them as much as possible.

Answer (score -1):

One does not need to spend years in the regex tag to notice that a high percentage of questions are coming from users who do not know regex. For some of us, reviewing these questions can get wearisome. The right course of action is to step away and do something else for a while, but I suppose some users start to click "close" and "downvote" while drooling on their keyboard a little.

However, this does not fully explain the behavior here. Many regex questions fall into a grey area. Matching can be pretty complicated, but there are many, many, *many* resources available to anyone interested in learning. [Researching your question before asking is an important, even essential, step.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/211627)

This question in particular basically boils down to a simple pattern:

1. List of requirements
2. Give me the codez

While the list of detailed requirements was pretty good (and that is saying something!), there was no appearance of effort on the part of the asker. *Maybe* they struggled for hours behind the scenes, but they have not show any of that work.

Showing your work, and whether or not it is required, has been discussed ad nauseum, so I won't reopen that discussion here. Feel free to read the discussion in [Should Stack Exchange in general be awarding "A"s for Effort?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210840).

I can see that the Meta effect has taken hold and now both the question and answer have been more than compensated for their trouble, but in future keep in mind that low effort questions are risky to spend time on. You *might* be able to get your answer posted in time before the question is closed, but you will still have to contend with downvoters who will downvote users just for answering questions they perceive as bad, whether or not the answer itself is bad (see [Guilty by Association](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251488/211627))

As a final word, Stack Overflow has *always* had a high bar for posts. It's a very big community, so standards can vary a lot between readers, but there is no quantifiable decline, or incline, or deterioration or improvement... it's really just your impression. Users have been complaining about downvotes almost since the inception of the site and they will continue complaining about them. Characterizing it as a recent phenomena shows either a lack of experience or recent bout of awareness. Now that you've noticed... welcome to the club.

- [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758/211627)
- [What is Stack Overflow’s goal?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254770/211627)
- [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/191410)
- [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users)
- [What's with all the rude comments recently?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15143/191410)