# What can I do when a community is openly hostile?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, regex

This can be considered a follow-up to the following. Because it's the same people and the same problem, but I have a few additional questions.

[What should we do when one person tries to delete every duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405460/what-should-we-do-when-one-person-tries-to-delete-every-duplicate/405481)

1. What do you do when a secondary tag, such as regex, results in the downvote and closing of questions on a primary tag inappropriately?
2. What do you do when people take retaliatory actions via downvoting?

It seems like SO is aware of this, but I am not sure it has been corrected.

Consider [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74365139/how-to-recognize-a-regular-expression-and-its-sub-variations-in-r/74366187#74366187). It is an [R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29) question. It could be a bit more clear, but it's not a bad question. Any R user would know how to assist here.

However, the OP made the mistake of tagging this with one of the regex flavored tags. Using this tag places you at high risk of being subjected to hostile behavior. So despite being a decent question, especially for a brand new user, it was voted on to be closed, and downvoted twice (within minutes).

I proceeded to answer, but made the following comment. Yeah, maybe a bit aggressive, but enough is enough.

> Why is this downvoted so much? Can the regex mafia be a little kinder to new users?

I then pretty quickly began getting downvoted on other questions that I had answered. They are completely valid R answers, and some may consider them better answers than the regex gurus provided. Because they replace a convoluted regex with a more domain-appropriate solution.

- [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67834544/using-grep-with-two-arguments-in-r/67842485)
- [And this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69995001/how-to-strip-down-comma-separated-strings-to-unique-substrings/69995233)

To me, regex is a secondary tag, not a primary tag. What do I mean by this? It means that a question tagged as R, or Python, or Java is *first* a question about that language and *second* a question about how to apply a regex. In many of these languages, you actually want to do something else instead of a regex. But team regex seems to disagree and will provide their own vigilante justice to dominate the primary tag, and downvote solutions that do not use their tool of choice.

What do I do as a user about this openly hostile behavior on this site? Can I report retaliatory behavior via downvoting? How do I report a user (we all know who it is). Would that even matter?

Comment: How is down-voting considered unkind or hostile? We are supposed to vote on question and answer quality and site appropriateness, regardless of poster status, nothing less and nothing more. Also, the first question that you link to looks more like an overly broad work request than a SO question that would help future visitors, and I'm not sure if it would make the best example to illustrate your point.

Comment: When I make a comment that they do not like, and they go to my page and randomly downvote prior answers that I had, that is unkind and hostile. I also consider it unkind to downvote a brand new user's question while providing no feedback on why it was downvoted. Especially when it's not a bad question, but just not right for their tag (remove the tag and move on).

Comment: Ah yes, the "must comment when down-voting" argument, new-user subsection. Have you searched meta for previous discussions on this topic? Or have you been involved in prior discussions on this topic on meta? Just curious.

Comment: I'm sorry I am just very frustrated. I have watched this same exact thing happen on multiple questions, all with the same tag (I answer a sometimes overlapping tag). I remember having questions and not having a clue how to approach it, so I try my best to ask and tag the tool I think I want to use. To have these questions instantly shut down because they chose the wrong tag is just... wrong.

Comment: As for your other claims, about receiving retaliatory down-votes, that is something that none of us can prove or disprove, and should be flagged the moderators for their decisions on actions. Myself, I just accept that they occur on my questions and answers and move on.

Comment: The question received 3 downvotes and a single close vote. How is that a continuation of a user who tries to delete duplicates? How do you even know that the downvotes are due to the regex tag? I know a little bit about R, but the question doesn't look well researched. What are "sub-variations" of a regular expression? Even when putting that aside, there is no indication of what op has tried and it looks like a "do my work for me" request.

Comment: I understand your frustration, and the site is not very welcoming to newbies, I agree, but efforts to make it more welcoming have been tried and have not worked well yet. Right now, the biggest effort is with the Question Wizard (I think that it is called this), and perhaps this may help. But regardless, user status should not have bearing on how to vote on a question, not at all. The question should stand or fail, on its own, and regardless of who posted it, a newbie, myself, or Jon Skeet.

Comment: The question now has a delete vote. I think it has gone a bit too far now, as the question is not bad enough to be deleted.

Comment: @BDL the edit history tells you who removed the tag. It's the same user. You are right, it's not a perfect question. But to many R users, that is a pretty clear question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yeah, good points all around. I just I know I am not the only one to see this. Regarding some other points - I think there are drastically different cultures around certain tags. I think that can clash for sure.

Comment: @Adam: I do not disagree

Comment: There is actually a [\[regex\]](/questions/tagged/regex) tag here on MSO for questions about the users of that tag, but I'm not sure if it should be added to this question.

Comment: step one: Determine whether or not the hostility is actually hostility. Step 2, if it is actually hostility, is it hostility from the community, or a single unhappy user. Step 3. If it is a single unhappy user, *move on*. they have. No amount of further comments or frustration will fix anything at this point, the target of your frustration is gone. Flag any unfriendly/unkind or no longer needed comments.

Comment: I am going to the very sound advice of @KevinB and *move on*. Thanks all. I am not here for the rep (though it is fun). I am here because I like challenges and helping people

Comment: There was a similar meta question a few months back about similar downvoting behaviour in a particular tag (with very strict patrolling in the tag, that is, scrutinising *every single* question). Was it the same tag?

Comment: Yes, the same tag ([the meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419923) is from August). It (not surprisingly) [goes further back](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405460/#comment827145_405460): *"I admit that I (a fairly high rep user) am afraid to post questions in the regex tag. My first question in that tag got attacked (and I deleted it). I was a ~30K rep user at the time. ... you needed to be really really sure ... extra extra good and worthy question before posting one in the regex tag. (Basically, if a tag could be considered "unfriendly", then that tag is."*

Comment: @Adam Side note: "and tag the tool I think I want to use" - I assume you know that tags are expected to clarify what answers you need - you tag post with languages/technologies that should be used, so if you don't know what to use it is not a good idea to randomly tag post with what you heard somewhere (whether it is "regex", "c", "Java", "jquery" or anything else).

Comment: That is a bad question.

Comment: "I'm sorry I am just very frustrated" -> word of advice. Don't make meta posts in that state. And I am not joking.

Comment: "_Can I report retaliatory behavior via downvoting? How do I report a user (we all know who it is)._"  No, we do not.

Answer (score 20):

...why did you comment with that at all?  What value does it actually *add* here??

The synopsis of the circumstance, as best as I can interpret from this, is:

- Question gets downvoted
- You decide to answer
- You also make inflammatory comment about the downvoting activities on the question

I'm not going to sweat the serial voting since [there's a system that handles that already](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252271/1079354).  But I'm absolutely going to chide you for deciding to engage in a flame bait practice.

Use comments to achieve these goals:

- Clarification on a question (as in, make sure you know what the person is asking)
- Correction on an answer (as in, you can inquire if this answer is right or ask about a specific angle on an answer; if you think their answer is wrong, you can provide an answer yourself)

Do *not* use comments in the fashion you did.  The people that downvoted are anonymous; you won't know who they are, and knowing who they are won't matter in the long run.

Answer (score 12):

#### Frame challenge: improve the question yourself

I'm really confused by that question.  It's unclear why they're talking about recognizing a regular expression—there's no regular expression there to "recognize", whatever that means.  It's also unclear from the description what they want.  You sort of need to guess what they mean by looking at the output, and even then I'd be guessing.  In my opinion, the closure is totally valid.

You have edit and reopen vote privileges, so if you understand the question, you can edit it to improve it, then vote to reopen it.  It'll be reviewed by the queue.

We encourage improving questions you answer—we even offer three badges for it: Explainer, Refiner, and Illuminator.